# Understand complex command substitution with {} and multiple `\ls`

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to understand this line from a shell script. I know that `$(..)` means run the `..` and insert its output where you find `$()` in a statement. But what is going on between those parenthesis? What is the `\ls` doing and how does that relate to the `\` on the prior lines? Is that a `\\` split across two lines? Is `\ls` the same as regular `ls`?

```
APPCLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$({ \
    \ls -1 "$VOLTDB_VOLTDB"/voltdb-*.jar; \
    \ls -1 "$VOLTDB_LIB"/*.jar; \
    \ls -1 "$VOLTDB_LIB"/extension/*.jar; \
} 2> /dev/null | paste -sd ':' - )
```

Comment: I find it best to sometimes copy the command and get it running in commandline. So you can understand where it will end up. I know this sounds like a rude comment, but im not being sarcastic or sarcy. it is how i have discovered many commands and tricks.

Answer (score 5):

The output from the 3 `ls` commands is passed through to the `paste` command which merges them into the value:

```
$VOLTDB_VOLTDB"/voltdb-*.jar:$VOLTDB_LIB"/*.jar:$VOLTDB_LIB"/extension/*.jar
```

**NOTE:** The variables `$VOLTDB_VOLTDB` and `$VOLTDB_LIB` will be expanded and there may be more values than just one file for each of these `ls` commands. See the `*` there? That's a glob character which acts as a wildcard and expands to anything between the left side (voltdb-) and the right side (.jar) for example.

These would match:

```
voltdb-1.jar
voltdb-blah.jar
voltdb-12345.jar
```

Everything is then included in the variable `APPCLASSPATH`:

```
APPCLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$VOLTDB_VOLTDB"/voltdb....etc.
```

#### The paste command

Here's an example where I'm using the `seq` command to generate a sequence of numbers, 1-10.

```
$ seq 10 | paste -sd ':' -
1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10
```

You can see that the `paste` command is merging the output and separating it with a colon (`:`).

You can also mimic the example command like this:

```
$ { echo "hi1"; echo "hi2"; echo "hi3"; } | paste -sd ':' -
hi1:hi2:hi3
```

**NOTE:** The `-` to the paste command tells it to take the input from STDIN and print each argument as it comes in, separated by a `:`.

With different switches to `paste` it can also be made to split data up into groups, based on the number of `-`'s after it.

#### Paste Examples

Here's an example with 2 `-`'s.

```
$ seq 10 | paste - -
1       2
3       4
5       6
7       8
9       10
```

Here's 3 `-`'s.

```
$ seq 10 | paste - - -
1       2       3
4       5       6
7       8       9
10
```

So it's telling `paste` how many arguments `paste` should print on each line. But don't be confused, the example you're dealing with is simply taking the input from STDIN, separating each argument on spaces, and printing it followed by a `:`. When giving multiple `-`'s you're telling `paste` to take arguments, 2 and a time, 3 at a time, etc.

Arguments 2 at a time, separated by `:`'s:

```
$ seq 10 | paste -d ':' - -
1:2
3:4
5:6
7:8
9:10

$ seq 10 | paste -d ':' - - -
1:2:3
4:5:6
7:8:9
10::
```

Incidentally, if you include the `-s` switch you're telling `paste` to take the arguments in series (serially). Watch what happens when you use it on one of the examples above.

2 at a time:

```
$ seq 10 | paste -sd ':' - -
1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10
```

3 at a time:

```
$ seq 10 | paste -sd ':' - - -
1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10
```

Comment: Also, the bit with `paste` is a clever way to get the results into a `PATH` colon-separated format.

Comment: @kurtm - hang on until I finish my answers. I was getting to that 8-)

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize you were still editing :D

Comment: @slm what does the - mean in the paste command?

Comment: @akh2103 - see my note about the `-`.

Answer (score 3):

`$(command)` executes a command and substitutes its output.

`{ list; }` is a group command, executing several commands in the current shell environment. It's similar to `(list)`, but it doesn't make a subshell.

`\command` is used to ignore aliases to commands, which may alter a commands expected behaviour considerably.

The `\` at the end of line simply means that this line continues, so the shell will see the next line as part of the current one. Usually not necessary when this is obvious from the context (open parenthesis or quote).

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> APPCLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$({ \
>     \ls -1 "$VOLTDB_VOLTDB"/voltdb-*.jar; \
>     \ls -1 "$VOLTDB_LIB"/*.jar; \
>     \ls -1 "$VOLTDB_LIB"/extension/*.jar; \
> } 2> /dev/null | paste -sd ':' - )
> ```

`\ls` is like `ls`, except that if `ls` is an alias, the backslash prevents alias expansion. This guarantees that the `ls` command is used and not some alias that might add unwanted output such as a classifier suffix (`-F`).

The `ls` commands, called with existing file names as arguments, list their arguments, one per line. The option `-1` has no effect since the output of `ls` is going to a pipe and not to a terminal. If `ls` receives an argument which is not the name of an existing file, it displays nothing on its standard output and displays an error instead. Errors from the `ls` commands are redirected to nowhere by `2> /dev/null`. There are two reasons why `ls` might receive an argument which isn't a file: if one of the variables does not refer to an existing, readable directory, or if there is no file matching the wildcard pattern. In either case, the pattern is passed unexpanded to `ls`.

The backslashes at the end of the lines cause the shell to ignore the following newline. None of them are useful here since at every point where there are used, the shell expects an optional newline.

The braces { … } group the commands. The compound command `{ \ls …; \ls …; \ls … ; }` is piped into `paste` and has its errors redirected to `/dev/null`.

The `paste` command joins all the input lines with a `:` in between. It is equivalent to `tr '\n' :` except that it does not put a `:` at the end.

The command substitution `$(…)` causes the output of `paste` to be interpolated into `APPCLASSPATH`, after the value of `CLASSPATH` variable with a colon to separate the two parts.

Here's a simplified version. This is slightly different from the original in that if none of the wildcard patterns match anything, `APPCLASSPATH` will be equal to `CLASSPATH` with no extra trailing colon (which is probably desirable).

```
APPCLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$(
  \ls "$VOLTDB_VOLTDB"/voltdb-*.jar "$VOLTDB_LIB"/*.jar "$VOLTDB_LIB"/extension/*.jar |
  tr '\n' :) 2>/dev/null
APPCLASSPATH=${APPCLASSPATH%:}
```